# Is X the best there is?

Tags: mass-effect

I'm on my second play-through of Mass Effect. Since I decided to do this with the same character I had from the first play-through, I started off pretty high-level (I think around 50). In the beginning, it seemed level X equipment was rare-ish but still available. I'm now a good bit through the main mission, but still a bit away from the end. I've picked up Liara, and done Feros plus every side-quest I could get my hands on. I'm now on Noveria. However, I've yet to find any equipment above level X - and that's becoming fairly common.

By now, my primary shore party members (Shepard, Liara, Garrus) all have level X equipment in every slot and for every mod. So, I'm beginning to wonder: Is this as good as it gets? Is there no level XI?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, tier 10 (X) is the highest.**

All equipment caps out at tier 10.

See, for example, [assault rifles](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Assault_Rifles#Assault_Rifle_types), [pistols](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Pistols#Pistol_types), and [human light armor](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Armor#Light_Armor).